# Не работает PHP (Error: spawn php ENOENT)

Tags: php

Работаю в VSCode. Есть 2 версии php, одну скачал zip архивом с официального сайта, другая установлена при помощи xampp, пробовал добавлять в Path по отдельности и вместе (не помогло). А проблема следующая, при попытки запустить php коде выдает ошибку.

```
[Error: spawn php ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:506:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn php',
  path: 'php',
  spawnargs: [
    '-dxdebug.remote_enable=1',
    '-dxdebug.remote_handler=dbgp',
    '-dxdebug.remote_mode=req',
    '-dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1',
    '-dxdebug.remote_port=9003',
    '-dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1',
    '-dxdebug.client_port=9003',
    '-dxdebug.mode=develop,debug',
    '-dxdebug.remote_autostart=1',
    '-dxdebug.start_with_request=1',
    'E:\\Python\\DIGITLAB_Website-main\\login.php'
  ]
}
```

setting.json:

```
{
    "php.executables": {
        "v8.2.9": "C:\\php-8.2.9"
    }
}
```

Comment: Там вроде как путь к `exe` файлу нужно указывать [Custom PHP paths](https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/php-version#custom-php-paths)